# jQuery Validation on select not working as you go along

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Using jQuery Validation (i.e. https://jqueryvalidation.org/), I can't seem to get the as-you-go-along validation working for a select, e.g.

```
<form id="f">
  <div><input type="text" id="a" name="a" class="required"></div>
  <div>
    <select id="b" name="b" class="required">
      <option value="">Please select...</option>
      <option value="foo">Foo</option>
      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div><input type="text" id="c" name="c" class="required"></div>
</form>
<button>Save</button>
```

On fill and unfocus then unfill and unfocus, the text fields show an error but not the select. All fields validate as expected on `.valid()` though.

Fiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hq3b0ub/

Comment: `select` element too works well in your fiddle!!

Comment: Not for me @GuruprasadRao. What platform is that on?

Answer (score 1):

You may add a **valid** test on select change event:
in this way whenever you change the selected option the validator valid method is called and you see the error message before to submit.

The snippet:

```js
$("#f").validate();
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#f").valid();
});

//
// add the following:
//
$("#b").on('change', function(e) {
  $(this).valid();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="f">
    <div><input type="text" id="a" name="a" class="required"></div>
    <div>
        <select id="b" name="b" class="required">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <option value="foo">Foo</option>
            <option value="bar">Bar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div><input type="text" id="c" name="c" class="required"></div>
</form>
<button>Save</button>
```